# How does Ubuntu theme GDM?

Tags: themes, gdm

I’ve checked a few things already.

The file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` is stock GNOME.
The directory `/etc/gdm3/` contains no mention of “Yaru” or “theme” except for commented out lines, ditto for `/usr/share/gdm/`.
I’ve also taken a cursory glance at `/var/lib/gdm3/greeter-dconf-defaults` using `strings`, and it doesn’t seem to mention themes or Yaru either.

I’m using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I am **not** asking for how to theme GDM myself with a custom theme. I am specifically asking how *Ubuntu* currently does it.

Comment: google "Ubuntu configure GDM" leads to [this](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/gdm.8.html). This explains **how** Ubuntu does it. (GDM is just a "program"  used by Ubuntu)

Comment: @kanehekili No, that does not explain how Ubuntu themes it. It says it reads a `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, but that doesn’t actually set the theme—I’ve looked at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian often uses "update-alternatives" to replace standard behaviour.
Ubuntu does so too.

if you execute

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep gdm
```

you'll receive:

```
gdm-theme.gresource   auto  /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

This implies that the **configured** gdm.theme.resource is not the original one, but a resource created by the yaru team.

**How to find out and how to change?**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm-theme.gresource
```

will list all available options (and shows which resource is currently used) :

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

In this example  yaru has been selected (the star indicates it), selecting "1" would change it to the original Gnome.

So how does Ubuntu (and other Debian derivates) do it?

They'll look into their `/etc/alternatives/gdm-theme.gresource` directory, where the link will be preserved:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan 23  2022 /etc/alternatives/gdm-theme.gresource -> /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

The linking goes on, check the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm-theme.gresource` which links to the entry above.